# Angular 7 - CSS Custom Properties (CSS Variables)

Tags: angular, postcss, autoprefixer, css-variables, cssnext

I'm trying to find solution how integrate polyfill/fallback for CSS Variables to project which is using newest version of Angular (7.0.1) with Angular Material (7.0.2). Problem is that `ng eject` is disabled at this moment, so, I can't edit configuration for **Autoprefixer** which is using **PostCSS** for which already exists plugins making fallback for older browsers.

**What I found:**

[CSS Vars Ponyfill](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill)

- JS Library for watching on inline styles, `<styles>` or `<link>` HTML tag but for using this I must enable `watch` option of this plugin what means, watching for any changes in DOM  (I don't like this solution)

[CSS Next](http://cssnext.io/)

- plugin for **PostCSS** (used in Angular build as **Autoprefixer**). I think, best possible solution but currently I'm not to able how to edit build/webpack config.

**What I can do:**

- sure, I can create own `@mixin` in `.scss` for handling property, value as arguments and then return fallback + value with **CSS Variables** but I'm not sure if there are not possible future problems with that, so, I will be more happier with already exists solution (e.g. **CSSNext**).

Have you, please, some idea how to reach this goal please? Thank you.

Regards,

striky..

Answer (score 3):

Author of [css-vars-ponyfill](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill) here.

You don't have to enable the `watch` option to use the ponyfill with your Angular app. If you prefer, you can call it manually anytime (after initiating a theme change, on route change, component mount, etc). The watch option is a just a nice "set it and forget it" option that most people favor for its simplicity.

Version 2.x of the ponyfill has recently been released which supports incremental updates and therefore offers a nice performance bump over 1.x as well.

Hope this helps. Feel free to open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill/issues) if you have any questions or would like to discuss further.

Comment: @jildenbiddle does using watch improve load time?  In angular I am initializing cssvars({options:)} at the root component oninit.  In ie11 I have a noticeable delay before my polyfill kicks in.

Comment: @Winnemucca - Unlikely. First thing to do is determine if the ponyfill call is being delayed (i.e. what is your app doing before the ponyfill) or if the ponyfill is taking a long time to complete. These are separate issues. If you'd like further assistance, feel free to open an issue on GitHub where we can discuss further.